# Scheme let-form

Tags: scheme, let

I have the following assignment.

> In this implementation, you must use let-form to define local name and
>   local procedures for PI, areac, and volumec. The procedures
>   TotalVolume and main remain to be global.

I have the program that was created in Question 3 here:

```css
(define PI 3.14159265)
(define (areac d)
  (* (* PI (/ d 2)) (/ d 2)))
(define (volumec d h)
  (let ((a (areac d)))
    (/ (* a h) 3)))
(define (TotalVolume)
  (let ((v1 (volumec 1 1))
        (v2 (volumec 2 2))
        (v3 (volumec 3 3))
        (v4 (volumec 4 4))
        (v5 (volumec 5 5)))
    (display (+ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5))))
(define main  
  (TotalVolume))
```

But now I am completely confused on how to use let-form to to change the code. I understand how let-form works, and I understand that for PI I can just use:

```css
(let
    (
     (PI 3.14159265)
)
(body)
)
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for this problem?

Comment: Your classmate had the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576357/convert-from-procedure-form-to-let-form

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the duplicate before :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is that some of the definitions depend on previous definitions (for example: `volumec` needs `areac` and `PI`), so we need to nest the bindings and define the functions using `lambda`s. Here's how:

```
(define (TotalVolume)
  (let ((PI 3.14159265))
    (let ((areac (lambda (d) (* (* PI (/ d 2)) (/ d 2)))))
      (let ((volumec (lambda (d h) (/ (* (areac d) h) 3))))
        (let ((v1 (volumec 1 1))
              (v2 (volumec 2 2))
              (v3 (volumec 3 3))
              (v4 (volumec 4 4))
              (v5 (volumec 5 5)))
          (display (+ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5)))))))
```

A simpler way would be to use `let*`, which allows us to define bindings which depend on previously defined variables:

```
(define (TotalVolume)
  (let* ((PI 3.14159265)
         (areac (lambda (d) (* (* PI (/ d 2)) (/ d 2))))
         (volumec (lambda (d h) (/ (* (areac d) h) 3)))
         (v1 (volumec 1 1))
         (v2 (volumec 2 2))
         (v3 (volumec 3 3))
         (v4 (volumec 4 4))
         (v5 (volumec 5 5)))
    (display (+ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5))))
```